# $\|f'(x)\|_{L^p} \le C \|f(x)\|_{L^p}^{1/2} \|f''(x)\|_{L^p}^{1/2}$ for smooth $f$ with compact support

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I'm trying to prove the following

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function supported on $[a, b]$ where $-\infty < a < b < \infty$. $2 \le p < \infty$. Then
>   $$
> \|f'(x)\|_{L^p} \le C \|f(x)\|_{L^p}^{1/2} \|f''(x)\|_{L^p}^{1/2}.
> $$

However, I got stuck since I can't find a way to effectively relate the three (I can relate $f$ and $f'$ or $f'$ and $f''$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus but the one that is left out is a headache). Could anyone give me a hint on this? Thanks.

Comment: For $p=2$, you can use integration by parts and Hölder's inequality to obtain the result.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro Thanks so much, this is really helpful. In fact integration by parts nicely generalizes to $p \ge 2$. So again I overlooked the obvious... Would you consider expanding your hint a little bit to an answer (or post as is if you'd like)? I can award you the points you deserve :)

Comment: Could you please state your generalization of integration by parts for $p\geq 2$?

Comment: @Luiz Cordeiro $\int (f')^p dx = \int (f')^{p-1} df = -\int f d((f')^{p-1}) = -(p-1) \int f f'' (f')^{p-2} dx$, then apply Hölder we get $\|f'\|_p^p \le (p-1)\|(f')^{p-2}\|_{p/(p-2)} \|f f''\|_{p/2}$, so $\|f'\|_p^2 \le (p-1)\|f f''\|_{p/2}$. At last apply Cauchy-Schwarz, or Hölder again if you'd like to think such. Hope there's no gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $I$ is an interval where $f'$ is positive, we have, by integration by parts,
$$\int_I |f'(x)|^pdx=\int_If'(x)f'(x)^{p-1}dx=-(p-1)\int_If(x)f''(x)f'(x) ^{p-2}dx,$$
and similarly if $f'$ is non-negative. By summing over intervals $I$ where $f'$ has constant sign, we obtain
$$\Vert f'\Vert_{L^p}^p=\int_a^b|f'(x)|^pdx\leq (p-1)\int_a^b|f(x)||f''(x)||f'(x)|^{p-2}dx.$$
By Hölder's inequality, since $(1/p)+(1/p)+(p-2)/p=1$, we obtain
$\int|f||f''|f'|^{p-2}\leq\Vert f\Vert_{L^p}\Vert f''\Vert_{L^p}\Vert|f'|^{p-2}\Vert_{L^{p/(p-2)}}=\Vert f\Vert_{L^p}\Vert f''\Vert_{L^p}\Vert f'\Vert_{L^p}^{p-2}$, thus
$$\Vert f'\Vert_{L^p}^2=\Vert f'\Vert_{L^p}^{p-(p-2)}\leq(p-1)\Vert f\Vert_{L^p}\Vert f''\Vert_{L^p}.$$

Comment: One minor point, $f'$ needs to vanish on $\partial I$ for the first equation to work.